# nosetests -h fails to run with error

Tags: python, nosetests

I suspect I failed to install nosetests correctly. 
I used easy_install nose - output was

```
Searching for nose
Best match: nose 1.0.0
Processing nose-1.0.0-py2.7.egg
nose 1.0.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing nosetests-script.py script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing nosetests.exe script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing nosetests-2.7-script.py script to C:\Python27\Script
Installing nosetests-2.7.exe script to C:\Python27\Scripts
```

So it looks like it installs fine. But when I run nosetests -h

```
PS C:\Users\john\code\python> nosetests -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\nosetests-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('nose==1.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'nosetests')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.0.0-py2.7.egg\nose\core.py", line 118, in __init__
    **extra_args)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exit'
```

Did I miss a setup step somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird. In `nose/core.py` the `TestProgram` constructor calls the parent constructor like this:

```
...
extra_args = {}
version = sys.version_info[0:2]
if version >= (2,7) and version != (3,0):
    extra_args['exit'] = exit
unittest.TestProgram.__init__(
    self, module=module, defaultTest=defaultTest,
    argv=argv, testRunner=testRunner, testLoader=testLoader,
    **extra_args)
```

Constructor of `TestProgram` in `unittest/main.py` accepts the `exit` argument:

```
class TestProgram(object):
    ...
    def __init__(self, module='__main__', defaultTest=None, argv=None,
                    testRunner=None, testLoader=loader.defaultTestLoader,
                    exit=True, verbosity=1, failfast=None, catchbreak=None,
                    buffer=None):
        ...
```

So... I don't know how this error could happen. Do you have more versions of Python installed? Is your nosetests really using the correct `unittest` module for Python 2.7? Can you look at `unittest\main.py` (somewhere in your `C:\Python27`) and check the `TestProgram` constructor, whether it has an `exit` argument?

Comment: I used easy_install pyunit to get my unittest - all I've got is a compiled egg. 1.4.1 version. 
Should I use a different method to get my unittest?

Comment: Ok I found unittest in C:\Python27\Lib\unittest - it has the exit=True argument as well.
Perhaps nose is using a different one, in PyuNit perhaps?

Comment: PyUnit was the problem. I deleted the PyUnit egg, and now Nose is working fine. (using the already existing unittest)